# Getting Capybara to wait for debounce

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

Using Rspec and Capybara after recently adding in a debounce to most of my pages the test now fail randomly.

Now locally these are passing fine but on Semaphore 2.0 I am getting the random failings on shorter tests.

We use WebMock to stub the request in remoteFetch() and it seems that this is removed on shorter tests. As this is called afterwards, the stub doesn't exist and the test fails

```
function debouncedFetch(ids) {
  store.idsToFetch.push(ids);
  $timeout.cancel(store.fetchTimeoutFn);
  store.fetchTimeoutFn = $timeout(() => { remoteFetch(store.idsToFetch); }, 200);
}
```

I have tried putting the debounce/timeout to 0 still with no joy.

Is there a way to check if tests/rootscope have finished or destroyed or something and not run the remoteFetch function.

Or get the test to wait for this function to run

Comment: Please show an example of a failing test - and the failure message

Comment: Hi the tests fail by saying
WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
As it can't find the mock that has been set up at the start

WebMock has a hook on after each that will call reset, deleting the mock. 
But then the request is executed as it's delayed. 
It doesn't always fail, and locally never! just on CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `after(each:) { WebMock.reset! }`  as part of the gem is called before `Capybara.reset_sessions!`

This causes a race condition in the code. the way around this is to change the order and make sure in your spec_helper that `require 'webmock/rspec'` is called before `require 'rspec/rails'`

This ensures the order of the hooks are setup in the right order.

hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the default Capybara configuration where Capybara manages the running of the app under test it will wait for all network connections to be closed during the test reset in an `after` block.  Since you're cleaning up your WebMock in an `after` block it's possible it's occurring before the Capybara registered block. To fix that you can change the order they're defined in or defined your WebMock cleanup with `append_after` rather than `after` so it's guaranteed to run after the Capybara session reset.

Comment: As the web request is scheduled to happen (in this case 200ms) after the timeout, the web request is not there/active/alive. The pending request is.
The WebMock Gem is the one with the after hook, I need to some how get it to wait for the pending function/request before rspec runs after

Comment: @RuAware So as your answer shows my answer was correct - you needed to fix the order the blocks were defined in.

Comment: Yes it is just the way in which the final solution I want to get across. In order to do that. Your help has guide me, i will award bounty to you when I can

Comment: @RuAware ok - don't forget to select the answer (`checkmark`) so the question gets marked as answered